# Why does TypeScript infer the wrong type for an object type but not a record?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am trying to write a TypeScript function that accepts an object with a key and value with type `A` or just the type `A`. I can write a function that takes `Record<K, A> | A` and returns `A`. However when I attempt to call this the types are inferred incorrectly.

```
type Key = keyof any

function hasKey<K extends Key>(
  value: unknown,
  key: K,
): value is { [P in K]: unknown } {
  return value !== null && typeof value === "object" && key in value;
}


function propertyOrSelf<A, K extends Key>(
  value: Record<K, A> | A,
  key: K
): A {
  return hasKey(value, key) ? value[key] : value;
}


const alice: { name: string } = { name: "Alice" }

// { name: string } and Record<"name", string> are equivalent
const alice2: Record<"name", string> = alice
const alice3: { name: string } = alice2

const bob: string = "Bob"

const n1: { name: string } | string = Math.random() < 0.5 ? alice : bob
const n2: Record<"name", string> | string = n1

// Doesn't Work
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
const a: string = propertyOrSelf(n1, "name");

// Works
const b: string = propertyOrSelf<string, "name">(n1, "name");
const c: string = propertyOrSelf(n2, "name");
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#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-uwoAAGHMAVkBarREJ9FStkbJWt5uuO+pxRtd51TSaJyWjxEZUAAIugIMw8AByJEAdUOKEII4AKuBoNOUljyhBQtO3CItDbmMxqATMeUFNBgOgcuuoNPXdOcxINXaNRqzE3VTh-eyB1AAxDLuYyTNMmASDGiydoaZjtMuTILqEKDMN+SLlH+gbIEBwygVMMzsK60FCpIUFQDBJRwWhUAUJhybYYMuEgOM+EQXgGrEQalHtEAA)

Why isn't it inferring the correct type for `a` when it does for `c`?

Comment: So you're just asking "why doesn't this work" and not how to fix it, right? If so it's going to come down to details about the TS inference algorithm that are hard to verify. In general, TS is free to try to infer `K` from `value` as well as from `key`. If `value` is of type `string`, then it's possible for `K` to be inferred as `keyof string` and then `A` to be inferred as `string[keyof string] which is a big mess of things you don't want to deal with. I'd be happy to write that up as an answer (with a little more detail) if it addresses the question sufficiently for you.

Comment: I guess there are really 3 parts to my question. 1) Why does `a` not infer the correct type, 2) why is that different from `c`, 3) what is the solution. I'll update the question to make that more explicit. At the end of the day I do need a solution too but I also like to learn. I think I'm mostly following what you are saying. I still don't get why that doesn't happen for `c`.

Comment: Reworded. I'll just ask another question for the solution then.

Comment: For `c` the compiler can pattern match on `Record` in both instances, whereas for `A` it needs to try to do a structural comparison and it picks something you don't like.  See [ms/TS#26815](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26815).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time on this. I'm really not sure what is going on. I'm still not seeing the difference between `n1` and `n2`. Isn't `Record<"name", string>` an alias for `{ [P in "name"]: string }`? (it seems no as I tried this and it fails in the same way as `n1` does)

Comment: The basic issue is as in ms/TS#26815 and [ms/TS#54000](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54000). When comparing `F<X>` to `F<Y>` the compiler can (sometimes) just compare `X` to `Y` because both are using `F`. But when comparing `F<X>` to `G<Y>` the compiler has no choice but to fully evaluate both types, *even if it turns out that `G` is just an alias of `F`*. So you can get different inference behavior for structurally identical types. Does that make enough sense for me to write up a full answer you're likely to accept? Or is there still a disconnect?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks.