# How do I infer the type of a property and they key from a union of the record and the value type?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am trying to write a TypeScript function that accepts an object with a key and value with type `A` or just the type `A`. I can write a function that takes `Record<K, A> | A` and returns `A`. However when I attempt to call this the types are inferred incorrectly.

```
type Key = keyof any

function hasKey<K extends Key>(
  value: unknown,
  key: K,
): value is { [P in K]: unknown } {
  return value !== null && typeof value === "object" && key in value;
}


function propertyOrSelf<A, K extends Key>(
  value: Record<K, A> | A,
  key: K
): A {
  return hasKey(value, key) ? value[key] : value;
}


const alice: { name: string } = { name: "Alice" }

// { name: string } and Record<"name", string> are equivalent
const alice2: Record<"name", string> = alice
const alice3: { name: string } = alice2

const bob: string = "Bob"

const n1: { name: string } | string = Math.random() < 0.5 ? alice : bob
const n2: Record<"name", string> | string = n1

// Doesn't Work
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
const a: string = propertyOrSelf(n1, "name");

// Works
const b: string = propertyOrSelf<string, "name">(n1, "name");
const c: string = propertyOrSelf(n2, "name");
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#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-uwoAAGHMAVkBarREJ9FStkbJWt5uuO+pxRtd51TSaJyWjxEZUAAIugIMw8AByJEAdUOKEII4AKuBoNOUljyhBQtO3CItDbmMxqATMeUFNBgOgcuuoNPXdOcxINXaNRqzE3VTh-eyB1AAxDLuYyTNMmASDGiydoaZjtMuTILqEKDMN+SLlH+gbIEBwygVMMzsK60FCpIUFQDBJRwWhUAUJhybYYMuEgOM+EQXgGrEQalHtEAA)

What do I need to change to `propertyOrSelf` to get it to work for `a` and `c`?

---

I asked a related question here [Why does TypeScript infer the wrong type for an object type but not a record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77622755/why-does-typescript-infer-the-wrong-type-for-an-object-type-but-not-a-record) but apparently I'm not allowed to ask for both the cause of the problem and the solution in a single SO question.

Comment: I'd suggest giving `value` its own generic type parameter (say, `V`) and then computing the type you expected for `A` from `K` and `V`.  Possibly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqqJYm).  That removes any ambiguity from how the compiler might choose to infer things (if `value` is of type `Record<K, A> | A` then TS is free to infer `A` and `K` in any number of ways).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?